# Mounting .img from internal storage as USB Mass Storage

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, usb, mount, usb-mass-storage

I am trying to mount an `.img` file from my internal storage as **Usb Mass Storage**.

There is an Android App named **[DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid&hl=en)** which does exactly what I wanted. I tested with this app and the app successfully mounted an `.img` file as USB Mass Storage.

But I am unable replicate the same manually.

Anybody having any information on how to mount .img as UMS ?

**Phone Details:**
    
  **Model :** Moto G 2013
    
  **Device Name :** falcon
    
  **Rooted :** YES
    
  **OS :** CyanogenMod 13.0

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the Terminal commands:

```
su
echo /sdcard/your_image.img > /sys/class/android_usb/f_mass_storage/lun/file
echo 1 > /sys/class/android_usb/f_mass_storage/lun/cdrom
setprop sys.usb.config mass_storage
```

(The location of LUN may vary for some devices, you can manually check/search for it even using File Explorer..)

If above commands fail, you might want to disable SE Linux by `setenforce 0` command to set it to Permissive, and try again..

Comment: I think I just used your xda post to install busybox.. :D

Comment: What XDA post? ;)

Comment: I remember you from somewhere but I can't remember where I saw your post/blog/something

Answer (score 3):

DriveDroid is developped by FrozenCow, and here are the commands he suggests to reproduce DriveDroid functionality without installing the software:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable
echo MYISO > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun/file
echo mass_storage > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions
echo 1 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable
```

These commands are quoted from his own comment in [this issue](http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/156884/), see the third comment *"The following can be used to test the functionality"*.

In the background, DriveDroid relies on an open Linux kernel feature called Mass Storage Gadget (MSG). You can find documentation about this feature [here](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/file_storage.html) and [there](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt) in order to have a better understanding of its possibilities.