# Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?

Tags: data-recovery, linux, usb-mass-storage

I'm trying to recover an accidentally deleted video from Huawei P10. I use Ubuntu, so I tried to recover it using `photorec`. The problem is that I can't see the mobile's internal storage or SD card storage in the list:

```
  PhotoRec is free software, and
comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.

Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
>Disk /dev/sda - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB (RO) - ST2000DM006-2DM164
 Disk /dev/sdb - 240 GB / 223 GiB (RO) - KINGSTON SA400S37240G
 Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB (RO) - WD My Passport 259F
 Disk /dev/sr1 - 3504 KB / 3422 KiB (RO) - Linux File-CD Gadget
```

<sup>[Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbCBll.png)</sup>

The first row is an HDD, the second row is SSD, the third is an external HDD, and the last row is present only when the mobile is connected to the PC.

The mobile is connected to the PC through a USB cable and I've set the Transfer files option. Same result with Transfer photos.

[image]

Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 8):

Connecting to PC through USB (MTP) doesn't expose underlying filesystem (`ext4` or `f2fs`) of internal storage (`/data` partition) to PC. But recovery programs need direct access to filesystem i.e. block level access and won't work with MTP (Transfer Files) which is just a client-server type protocol for data transfer.

You need [USB Mass Storage](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-3.18/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt) (**UMS**) which is disabled on Android 3.1.x and above, when [MTP was introduced](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/mtp/package-summary) and then UMS was discontinued gradually afterwards in later releases. See [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526) and my answer to [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205430) for details.

OEMs may add UMS configuration to their devices. For samples you may see `on property:sys.usb.config=mass_storage` triggers in `init.qcom.usb.rc` and `init.msm.usb.configfs.rc` files in a Qualcomm device source.

However it's always possible to enable UMS manually provided that kernel support is present. The process described below should also work for older devices those had UMS officially supported. You need **root access** or at least **custom recovery** to enable UMS.

---

### HOW TO ENABLE UMS?

[Android Composite Gadget](https://projects.osmocom.org/projects/quectel-modems/wiki/Android_USB_Gadget) driver (which is an [extension](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/9047fe43bc6715edbde00f8f4311f83483883879) to Linux kernel's [USB Gadget API](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/)) exposes Android in *USB device* mode to a *USB host* like PC. Different USB functions (like UMS, MTP, RNDIS etc.) can be configured and switched using `sysfs` interfaces. Later mainline Linux kernel added the ability to [configure USB gadget modes through `configfs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/gadget_configfs.html) interfaces. New Android devices also use the same (see this [sample `init`'s `.rc`](https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/cuttlefish/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/shared/config/init.hardware.usb.rc#26) file).

**OLD DEVICES:**

Kernel must be built with `CONFIG_USB_F_MASS_STORAGE` and Android Composite Gadget driver (`CONFIG_USB_G_ANDROID`):

```
cd /sys/class/android_usb/android0
echo -n 0 >enable
echo -n '/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata' >f_mass_storage/lun/file
echo -n 'mass_storage' >functions
echo -n <VID> >idVendor
echo -n <PID> >idProduct
echo -n 1 >enable
```

<sup>* Other files in gadget such as `{iSerial,iProduct,iManufacturer}` are usually set on device boot when creating the gadget.</sup>

**NEW DEVICES:**

Kernel must be built with `CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_MASS_STORAGE`:

```
cd /config/usb_gadget/g1
echo -n 'msc' >configs/b.1/strings/0x409/configuration
echo -n <VID> >idVendor
echo -n <PID> >idProduct
for f in configs/b.1/f*; do rm $f; done
ln -s functions/mass_storage.0 configs/b.1/f1
echo -n '/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata' >configs/b.1/f1/lun.0/file
```

<sup>* Other files in gadget such as `UDC` and `strings/0x409/{manufacturer,product,serialnumber}` are usually set on device boot when creating the gadget.</sup>

**NOTES:**

- Paths may vary - including directories `g1`, `b.1`, `f1` etc. - depending on device and the hard-coded configuration.
- In most cases you need to set proper USB Vendor ID (VID) and Product ID (PID) to make the PC identify the mass storage device. E.g. `05C6` is Qualcomm's VID and [`1000`](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/05c6/1000) is their PID for UMS device. See `.rc` files on your device for device specific IDs.
- Exposing mounted `/data` filesystem to UMS may corrupt the filesystem, and must be avoided. Use UMS in recovery mode.
- If your `/data` partition is [FDE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk) encrypted, you need to decrypt it before exposing to UMS.
- **To make sure your data is recoverable**, see my answer to [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213275)

Now `/data` will appear as a partition on Linux PC which you can mount (preferably read-only to avoid overwriting data). However recovery tools including `extundelete` mostly don't need mounting filesystems.

If you have custom recovery, another option is to `dd` out an image of `/data` partition to external SD card and then mount it on Linux PC as a loop file. For this and other options to access internal storage at block level, see my answers to related questions.

**PS:**
Using the same methods it's possible to expose a ***loop file*** like ISO image or any other filesystem as UMS or CDROM device by writing its path instead of block device path.

---

**RELATED:**

- [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526)
- [How to take full image backup of partitions or eMMC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203913/218526)
- [Is there any way to recover data from 2nd SD partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190852/218526)