# How to expose a folder to a PC using mount command

Tags: usb, file-system, file-transfer, mtp, file-permissions

I've been messing with termux on a rooted tablet (mediatek), and I'm trying to expose a folder using `mount` that will be accessible to my PC via a USB connection over mtp (with read/write permission).

I've tried various iterations with `mount`, all to no avail. I can't find any tutorials explaining how this is done, so I'm basically relying on `mount --help` and trying to copy the logic of directories that are already mounted.

Any help with the CLI syntax regarding this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you will succeed using mout. MTP is as far as I know provided by a daemon which uses the Android MediaStore database for getting the file-list. May be you should better try to use on your PC a file-manager tool that uses adb for file listing and transfer?

Comment: Use [`adbfs`](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless). Or run a SSHFS/SFTP, FTP, WebDAV, SMB... whatever server from command-line. All of these are opens-source and free. Personally I've using OpenSSH and [`pure-ftpd`](https://github.com/jedisct1/pure-ftpd/) since long. Or find a suitable app. Like MiXplorer supports almost all of the above servers, though I only used FTP a few times. Or use directly UMS like a pro: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks. Using mixplorer looks like a good solution. I'd love to take you up on your UMS challenge, but I'm a bit to green in this world yet. I think I'll take the easy road for now :)