# make android work as if it's a real physical USB drive

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, usb-drivers, usb-mass-storage

It would be cool to make android behave as if it's a real USB drive when connecting the device to TV and PC(s). So we don't get things like "Unsupported" and make many things possible. I tried doing some diggings and found it was pretty easy in older versions of Android according to this  [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/q-an-app-to-make-my-phone-act-like-a-usb-flash-drive.1015076/) post due to USB mass storage.

Since it was possible to emulate as USB drive, I'm sure it still is possible now.

**In Android 4.4 I found a structure `sys>devices>virtual>android_usb>android0>f_mass_storage`. My guess is, this can be used for emulating USB drive(guess cause, I'm a total newbie yet to firefup Android studio and write code on it). But I can't find this structure on Android 10(`f_mass_storage` is missing). Is there there something like this in Android 10 or any workaround with it in Android 10?

**mount my system file. Create a block device mmcblk1(not sure if I used the right term, like /dev/sda in Linux). Format it with USB alike file  type( like /dev/sda1 in Linux ). And somehow direct to this location when a USB cable is connected to a TV or etc throught an app.  Also do I have build a USB drive protocal here instead of Android default protocol?, it's kinda getting messy.....

Am I with a wrong concept to pull this off? If yes, any advice how to do it? Also any reference/article related to it would be much appreciated (as mentioned, total newbie :/ )

Comment: USB Mass Storage (UMS) mode is thoroughly explained in my answer to [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205251/why-cant-i-see-android-storage-as-a-partition-on-pc)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I spent hours after hours reading the last few days(curse ggl and ddg). Your post/answer was so far the best! If its okay with you, from your expertise, can you recommend me a book(s)/article(s)/topics? I am curious on how android is exposed as USB programmatically! I will try to reprogram the whole thing myself in future, if I have the chance. Thanks for your valueable time :)

Comment: Update- I got the start line. Linux usb gadget. But I'm having hard time with tings like if my device have CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_MASS_STORAGE enabled) stuffs.               Any advice for this?