# Is it possible to turn an Android device into a USB Pendrive on a rooted device through a OTG cable?

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

I tried using USB Mountr but it turns up as `Linux File-CD Usb Gadget Device` and it doesn't work for my car's music player. Is it possible to emulate a USB flash drive using an OTG cable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205251/why-cant-i-see-android-storage-as-a-partition-on-pc)

Comment: That seems to be the same Gadget API that caused the problem in my question, I was wondering if it was possible to make Android emulate a general USB flash drive?

Comment: Android runs on Linux kernel, and in Linux kernel, USB Gadget API is the only way to make a USB Host act as a USB Device. There's no other general or specific way AFAIK. // "It doesn't work" is a vague description of the problem. You'll get better help from community if you explain your problem and findings in detail. What have you tried so far and what errors did you get?

Answer (score 1):

How I solved a similar situation few years back was by mounting the device after booting to TWRP/custom recovery... That way your device behaves like a USB Pendrive