# How to mount a partition on an Android device that can be read by USB on a computer when plugged in

Tags: usb, partitions, mount, usb-connection-mode

I have a tablet that I'm doing some hacky work on. This tablet comes from the factory with a small storage partition called USERDATA, that's about 5gb. It also comes with a large storage partition called SDCARD, which is about 20gb. The 20gb partition is USB plug and play, and as soon as the tablet is pugged in, I can access it with RW permissions on a PC.

I need to flash the system partition with a modded system partition, which I have done successfully. The problem is, for some reason the modded system partition doesn't automatically mount the SDCARD partition. I'm able to mount it using the typical:

```
mount -o rw /dev/block/...
```

This works, but I no longer can access this partition on the PC over USB.

Based on the little bit of stuff I've found that seems related, it seems that there's a way to configure a daemon process that enables MTP for specific partitions.. But I can't find anything that explains how to go about it.

Any insight on how to mount a partition that allows USB access would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205251/why-cant-i-see-android-storage-as-a-partition-on-pc)

Comment: @IrfanLatif Not really. I've studied that answer multiple times, and I still can't seem to make heads or tails of it. It says UMS is disabled on Android 3.x and later. Well, the partition in question must not be using UMS, because it works before I flash the system partition. My question is, what mechanism is this SDCARD using to be available via usb, and how to I do the same when I remount the partition?

Comment: MTP use MediaStorageDatabase so I don't think it is configured an a certain partition or may be only indirectly through the configuration that tell this database what to index..

Answer (score 0):

On some Android OS, you'll find A and B partitions on the drive in question. And from what I think, you haven't flashed it the way it's supposed to.

And on, for example, Chromecast with Google TV, you can only use FAT32　(strange because on most Android devices, you can read/write with exFAT). As long as you use exFAT, devices like PS4, PCs, tablets/phones, and even some TVs.

I always use exFAT for different device interactions, because it works beautifully. But it hasn't been Microsoft's main filesystem even though it's around 10 years old or soon will be, but they're sticking to NTFS　(I guess it's more security safe, and a file safe copy thing, I don't remember, long time since I went through this)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).